# Add Resolutions to Visual Studio Simulator for Windows 10 UWP Apps

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, simulator

How can i add/ change resolution in default resolution list in win 10 Visual Studio 2015 Simulator

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add more resolutions to the Simulator by creating an XML configuration like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ArrayOfHardwareConfiguration xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <HardwareConfiguration>
        <Name>Surface55</Name>
        <DisplayName>Surface 55"</DisplayName>
        <Resolution>
            <Height>1080</Height>
            <Width>1920</Width>
        </Resolution>
        <DeviceSize>55</DeviceSize>
        <DeviceScaleFactor>100</DeviceScaleFactor>
    </HardwareConfiguration>
</ArrayOfHardwareConfiguration>
```

You'll want to name the file as follows:

> HardwareConfigurations-{Name}.xml

In my example, that would be:

> HardwareConfigurations-Surface55.xml

And then popping the XML file into the following folder replacing {version} with the version you have installed:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\{version}\HardwareConfigurations

Create this folder named `HardwareConfigurations` if not already present

Comment: I dont have a Hardware configuration in this C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Simulator\14.0\
 folder. what to do then??

Comment: Is there a filename convention??

Comment: HardwareConfigurations-{Name}.xml, so in my example it would be, HardwareConfigurations-Surface55.xml. I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore with Visual Studio 2019, i get the following error when clicking on the resolution button if i add the mentionned file to the folder
`No available resolution supported`

Comment: @alvinmeimoun For me, it is working as of now. I am using VS 2019 16.7.1 with Windows Simulator version 16. I have successfully go with the above mentioned steps and created "Surface Go" screen. No error message at all. Maybe some errors in XML that you've created?